# How to Decode XML Escape Codes During PDF Flattening?

Tags: xml, pdf, itext, xfa

I'm using iTextSharp to fill a PDF with XFA form with XML data using the
following code. if I write the bytes out to a PDF file I can open it and see 
that characters in the XML attributes such as `&amp;` are shown as `&`.

```
public static byte[] FillDynamicPdf(XElement templateXml, PdfReader reader)
{
    using (var pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        templateXml.Save(xmlStream);
        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, pdfStream))
        {
            stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(xmlStream);
        }
        return pdfStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

However, when I use the XFAFlattener (with paid license) on the resulting
byte array the `&amp;` shows up in the final PDF.  I've searched around 
quite a bit and can't seem to find anyone else posting the same issue or any 
good API documentation.  Anyone out there had the same issue?  Seems like it 
must be pretty common.

Here's a code snippet on our flattening process - may be some syntax errors 
as I had to copy and paste the relevant lines from our code to get it to fit 
nicely in this question area.

```
byte[] pdfStream = getFormFilledPDFBytes();
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
var document = new Document();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream);
var reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
var xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
xfaf.Flatten(reader);
var flatPdf = outputStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Since you have a paid license, you should contact iText support via email or Jira, and iText developers will help you directly. Community support on StackOverflow does not guarantee an answer.

Comment: Tip: the "question area" is not limited to the smallish box you see on screen. It scrolls when you add more data to it. Best review your *possibly* bad code snippet and make sure it compiles, as in [mcve].

Comment: I did not find any David Nordstedt in our JIRA users, nor any user with a  alternatephotography.com email address (your public SO profile), so I don't know how to contact you. Each customer can register up to 3 email addresses for support, so maybe your company is registered under another email address? I did however find someone with your name on LinkedIn and the employer is an iText customer, but uses another email address for technical support.

Comment: Rad, thanks for the tip!  I'll keep that in mind.  Amedee, we just put in my infiniteenergy.com email address yesterday for support.  I haven't received an email back yet, so it must still be processing.  I'll go ahead and send an email to support.  Thanks!